# Rails: #update_attribute vs #update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, update-attributes

```ruby
obj.update_attribute(:only_one_field, 'Some Value')
obj.update_attributes(field1: 'value', field2: 'value2', field3: 'value3')
```

Both of these will update an object without having to explicitly tell ActiveRecord to update.

Rails API says:

> update_attribute
>
> Updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure. This is especially useful for boolean flags on existing records. The regular update_attribute  method in Base is replaced with this when the validations module is mixed in, which it is by default.

> update_attributes
>
> Updates all the attributes from the passed-in Hash and saves the record. If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and false will be returned.

So if I don't want to have the object validated I should use `#update_attribute`. What if I have this update on a `#before_save`, will it stackoverflow?

My question is does `#update_attribute` also bypass the before save or just the validation.

Also, what is the correct syntax to pass a hash to `#update_attributes` ... check out my example at the top.

Comment: Why do you want to put an `update_attribute` statement inside a `before_save` callback? I can't think of a good reason for this.

Comment: I have objects that need to be updated based on the what the updated object's amount is. What is better way?

Comment: Am I right, that the objects you need to update are attributes of the object you are saving? If yes, then you could just set them, and they will be updated along with the object that is saved anyway (because they are set within a `before_save` callback). F.e. instead of `update_attribute(:discount, 0.1) if amount > 100` you could do `discount = 0.1 if amount > 100`.
`update_attribute` calls `save` on the object, which is unnecessary in this case, since the statement is inside a `before_save` callback and will get saved anyway. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes and no. However, the status of the objects that you are referring to is contingent upon other conditions that cannot be processed before the save.

Comment: as a note, these methods skip validation but will *still perform* callbacks, like after_save ...

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Please refer to [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002336). On clicking show source you will get following code

```
      # File vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2614
2614:       def update_attribute(name, value)
2615:         send(name.to_s + '=', value)
2616:         save(false)
2617:       end
```

and now refer [`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002337) and look at its code you get

```
      # File vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2621
2621:       def update_attributes(attributes)
2622:         self.attributes = attributes
2623:         save
2624:       end
```

the difference between two is [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002336) uses [`save(false)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002329) whereas [`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002337) uses [`save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002329) or you can say [`save(true)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002329).

Sorry for the long description but what I want to say is important. [`save(perform_validation = true)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html), if `perform_validation` is false it bypasses (skips will be the proper word) all the [validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html) associated with `save`.

For second question

> Also, what is the correct syntax to pass a hash to update_attributes... check out my example at the top.

Your example is correct.

```
Object.update_attributes(:field1 => "value", :field2 => "value2", :field3 => "value3")
```

or

```
Object.update_attributes :field1 => "value", :field2 => "value2", :field3 => "value3"
```

or if you get all fields data & name in a hash say `params[:user]` here use just

```
Object.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Comment: Your statement about callbacks is incorrect, at least in `Rails 3`.  It says very plainly in [the comments in the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L173) that "Callbacks are invoked".

Comment: I second what @Batkins says

Comment: @Batkins still validations are not run - that's the most important part :)

Comment: The links above are no longer accurate at least as of **Rails 5.1**.  These methods were moved to ActiveRecord::Persistence.
You can find the updated info here: [update attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) and here 
[update_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes) Note: `update_attributes` is now an alias for `update`

Comment: This answer is rather outdated - links are dead, quoted source code Is no longer relevant in recent ActiveRecord versions.

Answer (score 76):

*Tip:* `update_attribute` is being deprecated in Rails 4 via [Commit a7f4b0a1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a7f4b0a1231bf3c65db2ad4066da78c3da5ffb01). It removes `update_attribute` in favor of `update_column`.

Comment: This is no longer true; the method has been re-added. See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6738#issuecomment-39584005

Comment: `update_attribute` skips validation, but respects callbacks, `update_column` will skip both validation and callbacks and wont update `:updated_at`, `update` is the normal function that will respect both callbacks and validation

Comment: will they make up their minds already.

reset_column, update_column deprecated also.

Comment: `update_column` is not deprecated, but `update_columns(name: value)` is favored. `reset_column` has been removed.

Answer (score 18):

***update_attribute***

This method update single attribute of object without invoking model based validation.

```
obj = Model.find_by_id(params[:id])
obj.update_attribute :language, “java”
```

***update_attributes***

This method update multiple attribute of single object and also pass model based validation.

```
attributes = {:name => “BalaChandar”, :age => 23}
obj = Model.find_by_id(params[:id])
obj.update_attributes(attributes)
```

Hope this answer will clear out when to use what method of active record.

Answer (score 13):

Also worth noting is that with `update_attribute`, the desired attribute to be updated doesn't need to be white listed with `attr_accessible` to update it as opposed to the mass assignment method `update_attributes` which will only update `attr_accessible` specified attributes.

Answer (score 9):

`update_attribute` simply updates only one attribute of a model, but we can pass multiple attributes in `update_attributes` method.

Example:

```
user = User.last

#update_attribute
user.update_attribute(:status, "active")
```

It pass the validation

```
#update_attributes
user.update_attributes(first_name: 'update name', status: "active")
```

it doesn't update if validation fails.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in visiting this blog post concerning all the possible ways to assign an attribute or update record (updated to Rails 4) `update_attribute, update, update_column, update_columns etc.` http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/. For example it differs in aspects such as running validations, touching object's updated_at or triggering callbacks.

As an answer to the OP's question `update_attribute` does not by pass callbacks.

Comment: Yea sure, I modified the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Great answers.
notice that as for ruby 1.9 and above you could (and i think should) use the new hash syntax for update_attributes:

```
Model.update_attributes(column1: "data", column2: "data")
```

Answer (score 5):

`update_attribute` and `update_attributes` are similar, but
with one big difference: `update_attribute` **does not** run validations.

Also:

- `update_attribute` is used to update record with *single* attribute.

  ```rb
  Model.update_attribute(:column_name, column_value1)
  ```
- `update_attributes` is used to update record with *multiple* attributes.

  ```rb
  Model.update_attributes(:column_name1 => column_value1, :column_name2 => column_value2, ...)
  ```

These two methods are really easy to confuse given their similar names and works. Therefore, `update_attribute` is being removed in favor of `update_column`.

Now, in **Rails4** you can use `Model.update_column(:column_name, column_value)` at the place of `Model.update_attribute(:column_name, column_value)`

[Click here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a7f4b0a1231bf3c65db2ad4066da78c3da5ffb01) to get more info about `update_column`.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, `update_attribute` skips pre save "validations" but it *still runs* any other callbacks like `after_save` etc. So if you really want to "just update the column and skip any AR cruft" then you need to use (apparently)

`Model.update_all(...)` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7243777/32453

Answer (score 3):

Recently I ran into `update_attribute` vs. `update_attributes` and validation issue, so similar names, so different behavior, so confusing.

In order to pass hash to `update_attribute` and bypass validation you can do:

```
object = Object.new
object.attributes = {
  field1: 'value',
  field2: 'value2',
  field3: 'value3'
}
object.save!(validate: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is if having an update_attribute in a before_save will lead to and endless loop (of update_attribute calls in before_save callbacks, originally triggered by an update_attribute call)

I'm pretty sure it does bypass the before_save callback since it doesn't actually save the record. You can also save a record without triggering validations by using

Model.save false