# How to "update_attributes" without executing "before_save"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter, update-attributes, before-save

I have a `before_save` in my `Message` model defined like this:

```
   class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
     before_save lambda { foo(publisher); bar }
   end
```

When I do:

```
   my_message.update_attributes(:created_at => ...)
```

`foo` and `bar` are executed.

Sometimes, I would like to update message's fields without executing `foo` and `bar`.

How could I update, for example, the `created_at` field (in the database) without executing `foo` and `bar` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In rails 3.1 you will use [update_column](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column).

Otherwise:

In general way, the most elegant way to bypass callbacks is the following:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :skip_callbacks
  before_save lambda { foo(publisher); bar }, :unless => :skip_callbacks # let's say you do not want this callback to be triggered when you perform batch operations
end
```

Then, you can do:

```
Message.skip_callbacks = true # for multiple records
my_message.update_attributes(:created_at => ...)
Message.skip_callbacks = false # reset
```

Or, just for one record:

```
my_message.update_attributes(:created_at => ..., :skip_callbacks => true)
```

If you need it specifically for a `Time` attribute, then `touch` will do the trick as mentioned by @lucapette .

Comment: Looks like a good general solution! One question: What exactly `Message.batch = true` do ?

Comment: It is just a flag. You can replace it by whatever you want.

Comment: This won't work on serialized columns (update_column, that is), as it skips serialization / deserialization as well for some reason.

Comment: Worth noting that using update_column will also mean validations are not run.

Comment: Since you are setting an attribute on the class, this doesn't seem very thread-safe. Thoughts?

Answer (score 17):

`update_all` won't trigger callbacks

```
my_message.update_all(:created_at => ...)
# OR
Message.update_all({:created_at => ...}, {:id => my_message.id})
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

Comment: `my_message.update_all(:created_at => ...)` issues a syntax error, but the second option works fine!

Comment: my_message.update_all will trigger `undefined method update_all`. 
Message.update_all will do the trick

Comment: You might be able to use increment_counter [if it's a counter you want to increment] which also skips callbacks, I believe.

Comment: to work with instance you can use [update_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) or [update_columns](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns) for avoid callback calls

Answer (score 5):

Use the [touch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch) method. It's elegant and does exactly what you want

Comment: Looks like _almost_ what I need. The new value of `created_at` in my case is **not** the current time.

Comment: @Misha you're obviously right. So you can use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute :D

Comment: @lucapette: How? The docs says that `update_attribute` invokes the callbacks.

Comment: @Misha you can't. Thinking about your problem I was confusing callbacks with validation... So I think you should use update_all. By the way see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks maybe there is something i'm overlooking

Answer (score 2):

`update_column` or `update_columns` is the closest method to `update_attributes` and it avoids callbacks without having to manually circumvent anything.

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch

Answer (score 1):

You could also make your `before_save` action conditional.

So add some field/instance variable, and set it only if you want to skip it, and check that in your method.

E.g.

```
before_save :do_foo_and_bar_if_allowed

attr_accessor :skip_before_save

def do_foo_and_bar_if_allowed
  unless @skip_before_save.present?
    foo(publisher)
    bar
  end
end
```

and then somewhere write

```
my_message.skip_before_save = true
my_message.update_attributes(:created_at => ...)
```