# Changing associated objects don't get save with rails model object?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

having this code block of an example rails model class:

```
class Block < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bricks, :autosave => true
  def crunch
    bricks.each do |brick|
      if brick.some_condition?
        brick.name = 'New data'
        brick.save # why do I have to call this?
      end
    end 
  end
end
class Brick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :block, :autosave => true
end
```

I found that the only way to make sure the changes within the associated objects get saved for me, was to call `brick.save` manually. Even thought I use `:autosave => true`

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the autosave option has a misleading name. By the way, it's the expected behaviour. The option is meant for association. So if you modify an object in a relation and  save the *other* object *then* ActiveRecord saves the modified objects. So, in your case, you could change your code to:

```
  def crunch
    bricks.each do |brick|
      if brick.some_condition?
        brick.name = 'New data'
      end
    end
    save # saving the father with autosave should save the children
  end
```

Comment: better but not perfect ... but seems to be what most projects do

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the helper methods available: `update_attribute`, `update_attributes`, `update_column`...

More info: [Rails: update_attribute vs update_attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778522/rails-update-attribute-vs-update-attributes)