# `find_or_create_by` method are skipping model validation. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My `Tag` model has some validations for attribute `name`. It's wroking fine in all other cases. But when I call `find_or_create_by_name` by this way:

```
# The last value of this string (by coma) is empty.
# So this record should not be saved.
tags_line = 'ruby, javascript, '

tags_line.split(',').each do |tag_name|
  tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag_name.strip) do |new_tag|
    new_tag.update_attribute :user_id, member.user.id
  end

  # Just append tag to this model
  # through `has_and_belongs_to_many :tags`
  tags << tag if tag
end
```

But this empty tag is even being saved. So, can be something wrong in this code?

**NOTE:** When I remove the block, it works:

```
...
tags_line.split(',').each do |tag_name|
  # This way, invalid tag will not be created.
  tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag_name.strip)
  tags << tag if tag
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that attribute `:name` is protected in model. So, as the Rails Doc says:

> The same dynamic finder style can be used to create the object if it
>   doesn’t already exist. This dynamic finder is called with
>   find_or_create_by_ and will return the object if it already exists and
>   otherwise creates it, then returns it. **Protected attributes won’t be
>   set unless they are given in a block.**

The fixed code is...

```
tags_field.split(',').each do |tag_name|
  tag_name.strip!

  tag = General::Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag_name) do |new_tag|
    # :name is attr_protected
    new_tag.name = tag_name
    new_tag.user_id = member.user.id
  end

  tags << tag if tag
end
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could use the following type of method chaining if you rather skip the block

```
tags_field.split(',').each do |tag_name|
  tag_name.strip!

  tag = General::Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id(tag_name, member.user.id)

  tags << tag if tag
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last iteration tag has the string ' ', that is, a whitespace.

Try

```
 tags << tag unless tag.strip.blank?
```

as long as you're working with Ruby On Rails, which I suspect, as blank? is a rails extension.
Else

```
 tags << tag unless tag.strip.empty?
```

Edit:

update_attribute does not run validations. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778522/rails-update-attribute-vs-update-attributes)

Comment: It may work for empty values, but I want to validate format, length, etc. So Im searching for the root of this problem, avoiding repeated validations. Tks

Comment: You're right, sorry. Misinterpreted your question. I added some more info there