# Update_all or update_attribute doesn't update the column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I have a status report a user can send by email and I want to update a column :sent_mail to true, after the deliver action is completed.

```
def send_status
  date = Date.today
  reports = current_user.reports.for_date(date)
  ReportMailer.status_email(current_user, reports, date).deliver
  reports.update_all(sent_mail: true)
end
```

and the table class

```
AddSentMailToReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :reports, :sent_mail, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

However, in console, sent_mail is still set to false.Any ideas why this doesn't work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is because update_all sends an update directly to the database - it won't update the report models you have in memory. If you check the database after running your current version, you'll see that the records have been updated.

You need to call 'reload' on each report to get the updated version from the database or

```
reports.map(&:reload)
```

to do them all in one go.

Comment: `reports.reload` also works now instead of having to map and reload each record. Tested in Rails version 6.0.4

Answer (score 0):

If update_all or update_attribute does not work you can use this

```
reports.update_attributes(:sent_mail => true)
```

Comment: it still doesn't work..I was wondering to change it into Object.save != true

Comment: see this link. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class
and use it - reports.update_all(:send_mail => true)
-- check logs in background if possible send that logs

Answer (score -1):

Ref [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001798), [`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001862) and [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001861)

Change

```
reports.update_all(sent_mail: true)
```

To

```
reports.update_attribute('sent_mail', true)
```

There is difference between update_attribute and update_attributes [`update_attribute vs update_attributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778522/rails-update-attribute-vs-update-attributes/2778671#2778671)

Comment: `undefined method 'update_attribute'` because `reports` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`