# What to call this pattern of calling a method on each object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12598964/86421), I saw an interesting syntax for calling a method on each object in a collection in Rails (or is this really just Ruby?) I tried searching for it but I couldnt find any documentation on it.

```
reports.map(&:reload)
```

Is `&:` an operator? If not, what is it? What is it called? What else can be done with the `&:` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&: is called symbol_to_proc

And it is ruby not rails specific

Relevant link

http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html