# Updating database, what options do I have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner in Rails, and I want to know how can I update my database?(I'd like to know all possible options to do it).

I got simple table called USERS, where I got :name and :email attributes.

As i read I can update my :email by:

1. `User.find_by(:id => 1).update_attribute email, "sample@foo.bar"`       <- OK
2. `User.find_by(:id => 1).update_attributes :email => "sample@foo.bar"`   <- this return to me false

and is there any way to update it by:

```
@foo = User.find_by(:id => 1)
foo.email = "sample@foo.bar"
foo.save
```

Comment: in this thread you could find you answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778522/rails-update-attribute-vs-update-attributes)

Comment: btw `foo.email` should be `@foo.email`  and `foo.save` should be `@foo.save`

Answer (score 1):

`update_attribute` skips validations. So `update_attributes` is returning `false` since it's not passing some validation. Double check your `User` model validations and also make sure that under `attr_accessible` you've added `email`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name # etc
end
```

Also with `find` you don't have to specify the attribute, just use an integer:

```
@user = User.find(24) # this will find a User with the ID of 24

@user.email = "sample@foo.bar"
@user.save

# or update_attributes which can update multiple attributes at once:
@user.update_attributes(email: "sample@foo.bar", name: "Bob")

# or update_attribute which skips validations and can only update 1
# attribute at a time. Only used for specific situations:
@user.update_attribute(:email, "sample@foo.bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply update record by,
User.find(:id=>1).update_attribute(:email=>'sample@foo.bar')
as update_attributes is use to update all attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are two ways to update your data using ActiveRecord update.

**First Approach would be:**

```
ex. user = User.find(1)
    user.attributes = {
        :email => "sample@foo.bar"
     }
    user.save
```

**Second approach would be:**

```
ex. 
    user = User.find(1)
    user.update_attributes{:email => "sample@foo.bar"}
```

**You can also update using "update method" on your specific controller:**

```
ex.
 def update
  user = User.find(params[:user])
  user.update_attributes
 end
```