# Rails 4 change boolean value in db using button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on simple application to create your music collection. To add album to collection I am using Collection.rb model, it is working very well, but I decided to add a parameter :to_buy to Collection, and add second button "Add to wishlist".

collection_controller:

```
def create
@album = Album.find(params[:collection][:album_id])
current_user.collect!(@album)
@album.update_attributes(params[:collection][:to_buy])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @album }
  format.js
end
end
```

Code for button to add album:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.collections.build(album_id: @album.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
 <div><%= f.hidden_field :album_id %></div>
 <div><%= f.hidden_field :to_buy, :value => true %></div>
 <%= f.submit "Add to my wishlist", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Album is adding to collection, but I want to send value true to :to_buy in collection, and it is still null. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but to my eyes your controller line
@album.update_attributes(params[:collection][:to_buy])
should be
@album.update_attributes(params[:collection])
as it requres complete hash

Comment: maybe it should be like this, but this didnt change anything, still not changing value in db

Comment: just to verify try this
@album.update_attribute(:tobuy, params[:collection][:to_buy])

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this, current_user.collect!(@album). Are you devise or anything for authentication. how is curent_user object available in controller

Answer (score 1):

```
@album.update_attributes(params[:collection][:to_buy])
```

should be changed to

```
@album.update_attributes(:to_buy, params[:collection][:to_buy])
```

as you need to provide the attribute to be updated. I would also suggest to use where in place of find when querying over the model object.

Comment: I thought the syntax was `update_attributes(to_buy: params[:collection][:to_buy])`, rather than `update_attribute(:attr, "param")` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778522/rails-update-attribute-vs-update-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Although GhostRider has valid information, let me explain what we'd do for this:

---

**Custom Method**

If you want to update one attribute, I'd make a custom method in your controller & route to it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do 
    post :buy
end

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def buy
    @album = Album.find(params[:collection][:album_id])
    @album.update_attributes(to_buy: params[:collection][:to_buy])
    respond_to do |format|
         format.js
    end
end 

#app/views/
<%= form_for(current_user.collections.build(album_id: @album.id), url: buy_path(@album), remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :album_id %></div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :to_buy, :value => true %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Add to my wishlist", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```