# Why does update_attribute bypass model validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, module

Currently going through the famous tutorial. Having a hard time understanding why the update_attribute method bypasses model validations. Am I correct when I assume update_attributes is subject to validations and update_attribute is not?

**Helper:**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
   end
 end
```

**Validations:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  before_create :create_remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,      presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email,     presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness:    { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Rails base references itself, it is known that:

`update_attribute` updates a single attribute and saves the record *without going through the normal validation procedure*. This is especially useful for `boolean flags` on existing records.

See, http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute.

and if you want to know why it gets bypassed, the look in to the below SO answer:

[Rails: update_attribute vs update_attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778522/rails-update-attribute-vs-update-attributes?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Hope it helps :)