# NoMethodError in UsersController#show after updating users attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, nomethoderror

I am using the railstutorial.org book.
I tried updating the user attributes as written in Chapter 7 of the book, but the email became nil. I have tried updating to no avail. This produces a NoMethodError in UsersController#show: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass.

Here is the show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= @user.name %>
</h1>
```

Users helper

```
module UsersHelper
  # Returns the Gravatar of the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Please I need help to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: your `@user` variable is `nil` or it's `email` column contains `nil` value.

Comment: I think it is caused by the user helper. I created a new user now and the email was automatically set to nil. I deleted the helper and updated the second user attribute and it worked. Why is this the case?

Comment: @Emu the email shows up in rails console but does not display on the show page

Comment: Has the record been persisted (i.e. did you save it after setting the `email` attribute)?

Comment: `user.email` is definitely nil. Now you just need to work out why.

Comment: @Jordan it saves in rails console but does not turn up in the show page

Comment: @sevenseacat surprisingly it is set to nil. Here's a [screenshot of the db](http://imgur.com/FOTR7cB)

Comment: Please how do I work this out??

Comment: I added user model, help check if its from there.

Comment: First of all how are your updating the attributes? And if you are updating the attributes where is the `update` action in users_controller. Add the complete code and how you are doing it.

Comment: @Deep I am doing the update via rails console:

Comment: So what command are you using for it?

Comment: user.update_attributes

Comment: 1) If you do `user.update_attributes` in console, you need to pass a value for those attributes. How did you do that? 
2) In your User model, line 2: you call a method `:user_downcase`. I don't see the declaration of that method in your User class. Are you posting the complete code here? It's hard for others to see if something is missing if you only post part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also following this tutorial, so I don't pretend to be a Rails expert.

That said, I just went back and reviewed the tutorial material surrounding the first introduction of the

```
before_save { email.downcase! }
```

syntax, and I see this at the end of **Chapter 6** ([listing 6.42](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#code-downcase_bang)).

I'm pretty sure this isn't working for you because your UsersController is missing a definition of the "New" method:

```
    def new
       @user = User.new
    end
```

I'm wiling to bet that your @user object is Nil because you haven't create an instance of it yet. BTW, at this point in the tutorial, you should have also defined a Create method in UsersController.

**EDIT:** If your problems are limited to what is happening in the Rails console, I agree with the comments that you need to provide a complete transcript of your console session in order for folks to provide a complete answer.

Here's an example Rails console session from within my Rails Tutorial project:

1. Invoke the console and make it aware of my User model:

   ```
   $rails console  
   Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.2)  
   require './app/models/user'  
   => true
   ```
2. Create a User instance named "spong"

   ```
   **spong = User.new**  
   => <User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, remember_digest: nil, admin: nil, activation_digest: nil, activated: false, activated_at: nil>
   ```

(Note: My User model has more attributes because I am toward the end of the Tutorial.)

3. Populate values for name and e-mail:

   ```
   spong.name = "Yo Dawg!"  
   => "Yo Dawg!"  
   spong.email = "YoDaWG@dawg.COM"  
   => "YoDaWG@dawg.COM"
   ```

Note that my initial e-mail address is mixed case.

4. Invoke the downcase method:

   ```
   spong.email.downcase 
   => "yodawg@dawg.com"
   ```

This is working for me in the console. Now let's try the update_attributes method:

```
    spong.update_attributes(name: "The Dude", email: "dude@AbideS.org")
```

This is straight out of the [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#cha-6_footnote-ref-9), but it doesn't work for me, because at this point in my journey, I have implemented features that prevent this kind of update:

```
    (6.5ms)  begin transaction  
    User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('dude@AbideS.org') LIMIT 1  
    User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('dude@AbideS.org') LIMIT 1  
    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction  
    => false
```

As Hartl says:

> Note that if any of the validations fail, such as when a password is required to save a record (as implemented in Section 6.3), the call to update_attributes will fail.

5. So let me try the singular version of this command:

   ```
   spong.update_attribute( :email, "dude@AbideS.org")  
   (3.7ms)  begin transaction  
   SQL (4.0ms) INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "activation_digest") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "The Dude"], ["email", "dude@abides.org"], ... ]  
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction  
   ==> true  
   spong.email 
   => "dude@abides.org"
   ```

Not that the e-mail address is already converted to lower case in the INSERT command--exactly as expected, thanks to that

```
before_save { email.downcase! }
```

we have in our User model.

But what's with all the DB activity? This is because update_attributes updates a single attribute and **saves the record** without going through the normal validation procedure (which is why I am able to do this). While research this, I found [this excellent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778522/rails-update-attribute-vs-update-attributes) about update_attribute and update_attributes. Great stuff!

OK, so what happens if we try to call update_attribute when the (existing) e-mail address is blank? Let's see:

```
    newUser = User.new  
    => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, remember_digest: nil, admin: nil, activation_digest: nil, activated: false, activated_at: nil>
```

Everything in newUser is nil. Let's try to update the e-mail address:

```
    newUser.update_attribute(:email, "cOnFuSed@MixecCase.com")**  
    (1.2ms)  begin transaction  
    SQL (3.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at", "activation_digest") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "confused@mixeccase.com"], ...]  
    (0.9ms)  commit transaction  
    => true
```

Again, because of the behavior of update_attribute/update_attributes, my database is updated; somewhat counterintuitively, a record is inserted during this "update" process, but this is because I had not yet saved this (or the first) record to the DB.

I hope all this helps. At a minimum, I have demonstrated that this DOES work via the console--even with previously 'nil' values (and I learned a ton while doing the research to attempt an answer).

Comment: Yea, you're right. That should be the solution, was able to resolve it before your post. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Please mark this as answered so I get some reputation credit for all my hard work. :) Thanks!