# Update only one attribute using strong parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I intend to update only one attribute of the `color` model. The model has other attributes set to update via strong parameters:

```
def color_params
  params.require(:color).permit(:product_id, :name, :instock)
end
```

This update method works fine when updating the attribute `instock` without using strong parameters:

```
def update_stock
    @color = Color.find(params[:selected_color])
    if @color.update_attributes(instock: params[:new_stock])
      flash[:success] = "Stock updated"
    else
     redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

To use strong parameters I replace `if @color.update_attributes(instock: params[:new_stock])` with `if @color.update_attributes(color_params)`. This returns the error `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: color):`
I suppose that the error is due to a model validation that requires `product_id` presence.
A similar post [Should we use strong params when we update only one attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095241/should-we-use-strong-params-when-we-update-only-one-attribute) does not have an accepted working solution. 
Is there a risk of mass assignment when updating only one attribute and if so how do I use strong parameters in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose that the error is due to a model validation that requires product_id presence

No, that's because your params are like this:

```
{ :instock => '1' }
```

And your strong params definitions requires them to be like this

```
{ :color => { :instock => '1' }
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

It's important to understand the *purpose* of strong params: whitelisting. When you cherry-pick just one param to be assigned, that is another type of whitelisting. So yes, it's safe to do this:

```
 @color.update_attributes(instock: params[:new_stock])
```